# Simple complex conjugate question

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to find:

$$
\overline{\frac{-i \Gamma}{2\pi}\log\left(\frac{a^2}{\overline z}-b\right)}
$$

Notice the conjugate sign above the $z$ and that $z$ is complex.

$\Gamma , a,b$ are real constants

I am aware of that $\overline{\log(\overline {Z})}=\log(Z)$

I am just confused on how to write this conjugate. Can I just change the minus sign to a plus and remove the conjugate sign above the $z$?

Thanks

Comment: yes sorry, I didn't know how to write pi in the format.

Comment: What is $\Gamma$?

Comment: it is the strength of a vortex - so just a constant. Sorry, I should have explained this.

Comment: Are $a,b$ reals?

Comment: yes sorry, I shall clarify this all in the question. apologies all,

Comment: In this case, yes, `just change the minus sign to a plus and remove the conjugate sign above the z`.

Comment: yes and thats great then. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as easy as saying

$$\overline{\frac{-i \Gamma}{2\pi}\log\left(\frac{a^2}{\overline z}-b\right)}=\frac{i \Gamma}{2\pi}\log\left(\frac{a^2}{ z}-b\right)$$

In every example I have ever seen, the conjugate of the *whole* is the same as  systematically taking the conjugate of each of the complex parts. The are many examples in [Complex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate).

Comment: yes that's what I thought. Thanks for confirming!

Comment: Yeah, it's not an obvious thing and I think people over-think it. Just replace all $i$'s by $-i$.